# Is it possible to set the value of an aura component to an expression dynamically?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

For example, is it possible to bind the label of a button to a "myButtonLabel" attribute by adding an expression string like in the following example?

```
  $A.createComponent(
        "ui:button",
        {
            "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
        //EXAMPLE:    
        "label": "{!v.myButtonLabel}",
        "press": cmp.getReference("c.handlePress")
        },
        function(newButton){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (cmp.isValid()) {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newButton);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Lightning, expressions come in two types:

1. **Propery Reference Values** like `{!v.myButtonLabel}` which simply points to an attribute. For those, you can get the reference using `cmp.getReference("v.myButtonLabel")` and the values will be properly linked, i.e. the component will update when the value changes.
2. **Function Call Values** like `{!v.myAttr + 1}` which contain an equation. All markup in a component is preprocessed on the server and Function Call Values are sent in a compiled version to the client. You can't create a new expression from JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

you can make the dynamically created component's attribute point to aura:attribute but not to an aura:expression.

The key here is to use **cmp.getReference()**.

Like the one you used in your code `cmp.getReference("c.handlePress")` to dynamically attach component's controller method to `ui:inputButton`'s  press event.

You have to use `"label": "component.getReference("v.myButtonLabel)"` which enables an two-way binding i.e if attribute *myButtonLabel* value changes *ui:inputButton*'s label also changes and vice verse.

Incase, if you don't want any kind of two-way binding in the component's label, you use **cmp.get("v.myButtonLabel")** instead of **cmp.getReference("v.myButtonLabel")**.

Here's an example:

**Component:**

```
<aura:application access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="test" type="String" default="testBtn"/>
    <!-- change the value and ui:inputButton's label changes --> 
    <ui:inputText value="{!v.test}" label="Set label"/> 
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    {!v.body} 
</aura:application>
```

**Controller.js:**

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp,event,helper) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "ui:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "findableAuraId",
                "label": cmp.getReference("v.test"), // or cmp.get("v.test")
                "press": cmp.getReference("c.handlePress")
            },
            function(newButton){
                if (cmp.isValid()) {
                    var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                    body.push(newButton);
                    cmp.set("v.body", body);
                }
            }
        );

    },
})
```

Comment: To clarify, I'm wondering if it's possible to set that attribute to any expression, e.g. "{!v.myAttr + 1}" or "{!'Name: ' + v.name}"

Comment: @user3000391 As far as I know, you cannot set attribute to an aura:expression