# How to bind expressions to attributes when dynamically creating components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

With markup I can do things like this:

```
 <aura:attribute name="level" type="Integer" />
 <c:childComponent level={!v.level + 1} />
```

I can bind expression to child's attribute, and whenever attribute changes in parent component, it is automatically changed in child component. But I create component dynamically, so I pass attribute like this:

```
$A.createComponent(
    "c:childComponent",
    {
        "level": cmp.getReference("v.level")
    },
    //...
);
```

So I can use `cmp.getReference("v.level")` to bind value or `cmp.get("v.level")` to get raw value. How can I achieve combination of binding with expression like in markup?

Comment: Maybe you should use the [aura:valueChange](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueChange.htm) event. You could bind a new attribute set to level + 1 each time the level attribute is changed.

Comment: @MartinLezer that would work, but that requires extra code, I want to do as elegant as possible

Comment: Are you saying that I'm not elegant? :D Apparently there's no other way: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135804/is-it-possible-to-set-the-value-of-an-aura-component-to-an-expression-dynamicall

Comment: I just didn't want to create extra code :( but thanks

Comment: Not sure, but seems like you are doing some infinite loop when `level={!v.level + 1}`

Comment: @dzh No, it is determined by data. As long as object has child objects, tree goes level down https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-tree/blob/master/src/aura/TreeNode/TreeNode.cmp

Comment: I was about to say 'take a look at my component it might help' and realised I've actually wrote almost exactly same syntax! :) Anyhow, it's a recursive component, the only difference is it's using unbound expressions: https://github.com/sjurgis/lightning-hacker-news/blob/master/src/aura/Comment/Comment.cmp