# Lightning Inter-Component Communication Patterns: how to pass efficiently pass down data from parent to dynamically created child?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, aura-method

I know two ways of pass data from parent to child in the case of a static created child components: passing attribute values from parent to child and exposing child methods to parent.

The latter method can be easily used even with dinamically generated child components since the only thing needed is to give to each child a different `aura:id`.

I have troubles implementing the first method instead. I don't know how to pass an aura attribute to a dynamically generated child component but only how to pass a value. This means that I'm not able to change its value later.

Is it possible to pass an aura attribute to a dynamically generated child component? How?

---

Some references on the two ways of passing down data from parent to static generated child taken from a [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-inter-component-communication-patterns.html) on Salesforce Developer Blog.

#### Attributes

parent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="parentAttribute" type="String"/> 
   <c:childComponent childAttribute="{!v.parentAttribute}"/>
</aura:component>
```

child.cmp

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="childAttribute" type="String"/> 
</aura:component>
```

Of course, a handler in the child component could be used to detach a change of `childAttribute`.

child.cmp (new version)

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="childAttribute" type="String"/> 
   <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.childAttribute}" action="{!c.onChildAttributeChange}"/>
</aura:component>
```

childController (new version)

```
({
    onChildAttributeChange : function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log("Old value: " + event.getParam("oldValue"));
        console.log("Current value: " + event.getParam("value"));
    }
})
```

#### Methods

child.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:method name="myMethod" action="{!c.executeMyMethod}"> 
        <aura:attribute name="param1" type="String"/> 
        <aura:attribute name="param2" type="String"/> 
    </aura:method>
</aura:component>
```

childController.js

```
({
    executeMyMethod : function (component, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParam('arguments');
        console.log('Param 1: '+ params.param1);
        console.log('Param 2: '+ params.param2);
    }
})
```

parent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="parentAttribute1" type="String" default="A"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentAttribute2" type="String" default="B"/>

    <c:childComponent aura:id="child"/>

    <lightning:button label="Call child method" onclick="{! c.onCallChildMethod }" />
</aura:component>
```

parentController.js

```
({
    onCallChildMethod : function(component, event, helper) {
        var attribute1 = component.get('v.parentAttribute1');
        var attribute2 = component.get('v.parentAttribute2');
        var childComponent = component.find('child');
        childComponent.myMethod(attribute1, attribute2);
    }
})
```

Comment: Marking as duplicate of [Is it possible to set the value of an aura component to an expression dynamically?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135804/is-it-possible-to-set-the-value-of-an-aura-component-to-an-expression-dynamicall), as that has a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that this question could be intended as duplicate of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/135804/is-it-possible-to-set-the-value-of-an-aura-component-to-an-expression-dynamicall/136003) even if mine is a bit more general.

The solution is to pass the attribute by reference by using `component.getReference("v.childAttribute")`.